# Updating Value in dataframe is failing for a column

Tags: python-3.x, subset

[image]

Please help us on sort the below issue which is added with image:

I tried by applying `copy()` and `deepcopy()` function.

Comment: if you want help then place the text of your code into your post NOT a picture of it

Comment: You probably want to use df.loc[rows_to_change, 'column_to_change'] = desired_value

Comment: Ya its working , thanks